# havingRaw can't work in pagination in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

My code is written below

```
 $meetings = Event::select(\DB::raw("*, " .
                "( " .
                "6371 * " .
                "acos( " .
                "cos( radians('%s') ) * " .
                "cos( radians( lattitude ) ) * " .
                "cos( " .
                "radians( longitude ) - radians('%s')" .
                ") + " .
                "sin( radians('%s') ) * " .
                "sin( radians( lattitude ) ) " .
                ")" .
                ") AS distance"))
                ->havingRaw('distance > 0')
                ->setBindings([ $lat, $lng, $lat,$radius ], 'select')
                ->paginate(4)->toArray();
```

when i run this code i found this error

**Unknown column 'distance' in 'having clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `event_table` having distance > 0)","exception":"PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'distance' in 'having clause' in **

---

when i remove this ->havingRaw('distance > 0') line the output of this code is

```
"data" => array:4 [
0 => array:19 [
  "event_id" => 14
  "event_name" => "Test Event"
  "event_description" => "this is a test event"
  "event_live_url" => "http://www.facebook.com/event/test-event"
  "address" => "Mirpur, Dhaka, Bangladesh"
  "lattitude" => 23.810301
  "longitude" => 90.412498
  "creator_id" => 6
  "start_time" => "2017-08-29 18:42:58"
  "end_time" => "2017-08-29 00:00:00"
  "timezone" => null
  "event_phone" => "8801705092993"
  "event_email" => "rhythm.shahriar.bd@gmail.com"
  "event_facebook_page" => "http://www.facebook.com/event/test-event"
  "price" => 200.0
  "active" => 1
  "event_category_id" => 1
  "create_at" => "2017-08-29 18:42:58"
  "distance" => 10049.507140444
]
```

Now i can't apply logic to find 1km radius in that distance . how can i do this??

Comment: You can not use aliases from select inside having block. You must use there full expression you have in select

Comment: i don't understand . please can you explain me ?

Comment: In `having` block now you use `distance` alias which you create in `select` block. It is not allowed. In `having` block you must run the same expression you have in `select` block

Answer (score 0):

You can use  full expression in where statement instead of having eg.

`->whereRaw("(6371 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS('%s')) * COS(RADIANS(price)) * COS(RADIANS(min_delivery) - RADIANS('%s')) + SIN(RADIANS('%s')) * SIN(RADIANS(min_delivery)))) > 0")`